# Recomendation on learning Objective-C for C++ programmers

Tags: c++, objective-c

Is there any books or cheat sheets or online courses that will help C++ programmer learn Objective-C quickly.
From my experience, I can somehow read most of the Objective-C code in an iPhone app project and am sometimes confused about the symbol syntax, such as `+`, `@`, which are not easy to search online.

Comment: Get yourself a good book on the subject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an amazing pdf book called From C++ to Objective-C by Pierre Chatelier that I relied on when I learned it.  It's free on his website.

http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/fichiers/cpp-objc-en.pdf

Edit:

The pdf doesn't touch on some of the modern syntactical sugar that's been added nor does it speak specifically to ios development.  After reading the pdf I spent a few days on one of those learn to code websites (treehouse in my case) just to get a quick exposure to the ecosystem.

If your experienced in c++ that's probably all you need.

Comment: Great thanks! This document is just what I want to find.